# Saving self-signed cert to $env

Tags: command-line, powershell, environment-variables, certificate, file-types

I have currently just followed an excellent [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/95072396?noredirect=1) to create a new self-signed certificate so I can run my Powershell profile script in AllSigned mode.

This has worked ok but after having done this a few times (I had found other guides previously) I was thinking about simplifying the process (I understand there are many automation options out there), and wanted to add it to $env. If I do this,:

`$env:sscert = $selfsigncert`

where `$selfsigncert` is of type: `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate`

`$env:sscert.GetType()` returns `System.Object`.

I have garnered from [this guide](https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/powershell-one-liner-creating-and-modifying-environment-variable) that the below code is how to set a permanent $env variable, not $env:sscert as above, but I want to make sure the value is correct before I commit to that

`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("TestVariableName", "My Value", "<option>")`

Alternatively if this is a terrible idea security-wise I'd appreciate the warning

Comment: Environment variables are strings. To store your certificate in a permanent environment variable you'll need to convert the object to string (deserialize). And then restore it back. Why don't just save it in a file?

Comment: It was getting frustrating writing out the path to the cert but saving in a file could work yes, after you ask that very logical question though it has just made me realise I can just save the path as an environment variable and use `Get-Item`

Comment: Wait I just realised that I can't do that I don't think unless I index the return of a gci call - what do you mean about saving a file?

Comment: You can use Export-Certificate as described here http://woshub.com/how-to-create-self-signed-certificate-with-powershell/ to save to a file.